# Winforms Listbox.DataSource not working for some reason

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `Listbox` and I'm trying to set a `DataSource` to it.
This is supposed to be pretty simple

```
List<somekindaclass> list = new List<...>;
listBox.DataSource = list;
```

That didn't work. I searched around and found about `BindingSource`

```
List<somekindaclass> list = new List<...>;
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = list;
listBox.DataSource = bs;
```

That, unfortunately, didn't work either.

This is the `Designer.cs` code of the listbox

```
    // 
    // clientsListBox
    // 
    this.clientsListBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.clientsListBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
    this.clientsListBox.Name = "clientsListBox";
    this.clientsListBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 225);
    this.clientsListBox.TabIndex = 4;
```

Clearly everything should be pretty alright, but still, it isn't.

I guess I'll just pour my form code into here and you might find out what's wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ChatLibrary;

namespace ChatServer
{
    public partial class Server : Form
    {
        #region Private Members

        // Structure to store the client information
        private class Client
        {
            private bool Equals(Client other)
            {
                return Equals(endPoint, other.endPoint) && id.Equals(other.id) && Equals(data, other.data);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    var hashCode = endPoint?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ id.GetHashCode();
                    hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (data?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
                    return hashCode;
                }
            }

            public EndPoint endPoint;
            public Guid id;
            public PlayerData data;

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
                return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Client)obj);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0} : {1}", endPoint, data);
            }
        }

        // Listing of clients
        private List<Client> clientList;

        // Server socket
        private Socket serverSocket;

        // Data stream
        private byte[] dataStream;

        // Status delegate
        private delegate void UpdateStatusDelegate(string status);
        private UpdateStatusDelegate updateStatusDelegate;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initialise the ArrayList of connected clients
                clientList = new List<Client>();

                var bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = clientList };

                clientsListBox.DataSource = bs;

                // Initialise the delegate which updates the status
                updateStatusDelegate = UpdateStatus;

                // Initialise the socket
                serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                dataStream = new byte[serverSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

                // Initialise the IPEndPoint for the server and listen on port 30000
                IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30000);

                // Associate the socket with this IP address and port
                serverSocket.Bind(server);

                // Initialise the IPEndPoint for the clients
                IPEndPoint clients = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                // Initialise the EndPoint for the clients
                EndPoint epSender = clients;

                // Start listening for incoming data
                serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, ReceiveData, epSender);

                lblStatus.Text = "Listening";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Error";
                MessageBox.Show("Load Error: " + ex.Message, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Send And Receive

        public void SendData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                serverSocket.EndSend(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SendData Error: " + ex.Message, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initialise a packet object to store the received data
                Packet receivedData = Packet.PacketFromBytes(dataStream);

                // Initialise the IPEndPoint for the clients
                IPEndPoint clients = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                // Initialise the EndPoint for the clients
                EndPoint epSender = clients;

                // Receive all data
                serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref epSender);

                var sendData = GetSendDataPacket(receivedData, epSender);

                // Get packet as byte array
                var data = sendData.ToByteArray();

                if (sendData.DataIdentifier != DataIdentifier.LogIn)
                {
                    foreach (Client client in clientList)
                    {
                        if (client.endPoint != epSender)
                        {
                            // Broadcast to all logged on users
                            serverSocket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, client.endPoint, SendData, client.endPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Listen for more connections again...
                serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, ReceiveData, epSender);

                // Update status through a delegate
                Invoke(updateStatusDelegate, sendData.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ReceiveData Error: " + ex.Message, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private Packet GetSendDataPacket(Packet receivedData, EndPoint epSender)
        {
            Packet dataPacket = new Packet
            {
                DataIdentifier = receivedData.DataIdentifier,
                Name = receivedData.Name
            };

            ProcessMessageData(receivedData, epSender, dataPacket);

            return dataPacket;
        }

        private void ProcessMessageData(Packet receivedData, EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket)
        {
            Client sendingClient = clientList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.endPoint.ToString() == epSender.ToString());

            switch (receivedData.DataIdentifier)
            {
                case DataIdentifier.Message:
                    HandleMessageIdentifier(receivedData, epSender, dataPacket, sendingClient);
                    break;

                case DataIdentifier.LogIn:
                    HandleLogInIdentifier(receivedData, epSender, dataPacket, sendingClient);
                    break;

                case DataIdentifier.LogOut:
                    HandleLogOutIdentifier(receivedData, epSender, dataPacket, sendingClient);
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Identifier Handling Methods

        private void HandleLogOutIdentifier(Packet receivedData, EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket, Client sendingClient)
        {
            if (sendingClient == null)
            {
                HandleAlreadyLoggedOut(epSender, dataPacket);
                return;
            }

            dataPacket.Message = string.Format("-- {0} has gone offline --", receivedData.Name);
            clientList.Remove(sendingClient);
 //           clientsListBox.Items.Remove(sendingClient);
        }

        private void HandleLogInIdentifier(Packet receivedData, EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket, Client sendingClient)
        {
            if (sendingClient != null)
            {
                HandleAlreadyLoggedIn(epSender, dataPacket);
                return;
            }

            Client newClient = new Client
            {
                endPoint = epSender,
                id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                data = Serializers.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>(receivedData.Message)
            };

            clientList.Add(newClient);
   //         clientsListBox.Items.Add(newClient);

            MessageBox.Show(
                string.Format("New player:\nEndPoint : {0}\nGuid : {1}\nData : {2}", newClient.endPoint, newClient.id,
                    newClient.data), "New Player Connected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            dataPacket.Message = string.Format("-- {0} is online --", receivedData.Name);
        }

        private static void HandleMessageIdentifier(Packet receivedData, EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket, Client sendingClient)
        {
            if (sendingClient == null)
            {
                HandleMessageRecievedFromUnknown(epSender, dataPacket);
                return;
            }

            sendingClient.data = Serializers.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>(receivedData.Message);
            dataPacket.Message = string.Format("{0}: {1}", receivedData.Name, sendingClient.data);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Error Handling Methods

        private static void HandleAlreadyLoggedOut(EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket)
        {
            var errorLogoutMessage = string.Format("Recieved LOGOUT message from a player that's not in the list: {0}",
                epSender);

            MessageBox.Show(errorLogoutMessage, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dataPacket.Message = errorLogoutMessage;
        }

        private static void HandleAlreadyLoggedIn(EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket)
        {
            var errorLoginMessage = string.Format("Player already in list : {0}", epSender);
            MessageBox.Show(errorLoginMessage, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dataPacket.Message = errorLoginMessage;
        }

        private static void HandleMessageRecievedFromUnknown(EndPoint epSender, Packet dataPacket)
        {
            var messageRecievedErrorMessage = string.Format("Recieved message from player that's not in the list : {0}", epSender);
            MessageBox.Show(messageRecievedErrorMessage, "UDP Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dataPacket.Message = messageRecievedErrorMessage;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Other Methods

        private void UpdateStatus(string status)
        {
            messagesTextbox.AppendText(status + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be the server to clients that are supposed to connect from unity, not completed, just experimenting stuff.

Comment: What does "didnt work" mean?

Comment: When a player connects, nothings added to the list...

Comment: Does it need to have a "DisplayMember" or some similar property set? The reason I say this is that my code (somewhat similar, but uses a Dictionary<string,string> does:
Dictionary<String, String> dict = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetReportGeneratorsDictionary();
            comboBoxReportRunners.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
            comboBoxReportRunners.DisplayMember = "Key";
            . . .

Comment: It's not about the text format. I have implemented a `ToString` for `Client` and it does work when I add items myself. My point was not to manually call `Items.Add` and `Items.Remove`. But setting the `DataSource` doesn't work so I'll do it manually

Answer (score 2):

`BindingSource` is not needed. If you want the bound UI (`ListBox` in your case) to react to the modifications of the source list, replace `List<T>` with [BindingList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is similar, but supports change notifications.

```
private BindingList<Client> clientList;

// ...
clientList = new BindingList<Client>();
clientsListBox.DataSource = clientList;
```

All other code remains the same.

Comment: In my case, the list is part of a Server class, and I would want to leave UI elements out of the class as much as possible.

Comment: Then `BindingList<T>` is perfect for you. The name is a bit misleading. It's not UI element (part of a `System.ComponentModel` namespace, located in System.dll). As I mentioned, it's a `IList<T>` implementation with Add/Remove/Change notifications.

Comment: Is something like: `List<int> list = new List<int>(); BindingList<int> bindingList = (BindingList)list;` possible?

Comment: It's not possible, + it's also event based, so it doesn't change much

Answer (score 1):

After adding a new player to the list you should call the BindingSource.ResetBindings to force a reload of the control associated to the BindingSource

So declare at the global level your BindingSource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
```

and call

```
clientList.Add(newClient);
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Of course you need to do the same in every point where your clientList changes.

Comment: Currently I'm only having one player, haven't gotten to connecting several players to the server.

Comment: Sorry but then I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: One client connects the server, and then an item for that player should be added to the list box, but it isn't. Not a single one, not once.

Comment: You should use the debugger and check if the method _HandleLogInIdentifier_ is called or not. Put a breakpoint on it and run your code.

Comment: It's called, I've made sure plenty of times. If I uncomment `clientsListBox.Items.Add(newClient);`, It works.

Comment: Then did you try the solution proposed by me or better the one from Ivan Stoev?

Comment: My whole point was not to call `Items.Add`. Instead I moved all code relevant to the server to a separate class, and added events, like `ClientConnected` and `ClientDisconnected` and eventually I do call `Items.Add` and Items.Remove` myself. Without using DataSource.

Comment: I'll correct myself, I've tried saving a `SourceBinding` member and setting the `DataSource` of the listbox to it, and calling `ResetBinding` on my events, and it worked. THANKS!